# Get key of current value in hash table using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm having a problem, it looks simple but can't find a solution; I am iterating a hash table in PowerShell it looks like this:

```ps1
foreach($tool in $otherTools.GetEnumerator() | Sort Name)
{
   #tried echo $tool.Name
   #tried echo $tool.Value
   #tried echo $tool.Key
}
```

but nothing above works.
The reason is I want to use the switch statement inside by key.

HashTable looks like:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
One                           testone
Two                           TestTwo
```

Comment: Unclear question.  What's not working? What output are you getting? Errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it right. Maybe you used something like `echo "$tool.Key"` which will output `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry.Key`. To fix that, you could either use `echo "$($tool.Key)"` or a format string:

```
$hashTable = @{
    One = 'testone'
    Two = 'TestTwo'
}

foreach ($tool in $hashTable.GetEnumerator() | sort Name)
{
    Write-Host ("Name: {0} Value: {1}" -f $tool.Key, $tool.Value)
}
```

*Output:*

```
Name: One Value: testone
Name: Two Value: TestTwo
```